# Why are these loops in Ruby not outputting the same answer?

Tags: ruby

I am currently doing Project Euler problem 1. I have no idea why these two loops are not the same.

```
total = 0
for i in 0..1000
  if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    total += i
  end
end
```

and

```
total = 0
(0...1000).each do |i|
  total += i if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
end
puts total
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use three dots in range `(0...1000)`, the end value is not part of the range - it is equivalent to `(0..999)`

So, in first case `1000` is part of the loop, but in second case it is not.